# Trying to draw on canvas using canvas.clipPath

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw circle on darken background, trying to achive smth like this - [image]
This actually worked on my Samsung s4 and Samsung tab 3, but won't work on s2 and some emulator (all sorrounding viewgroup is darken, and inside oval too, seems like it does not see my circleSelectionPath). Help me please to find the way to make it work on every device

```
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#77000000"));

        Path circleSelectionPath = new Path();
        mRectF.set(l, t, r, b);
        circleSelectionPath.addOval(mRectF, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(circleSelectionPath, Region.Op.XOR);
        canvas.drawRect(bitmapRect.left, bitmapRect.top, bitmapRect.right, bitmapRect.bottom, paint );
        canvas.restore();
```

bitmapRect contains my viewgroup dimens (for example : 0,0, 500,500)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Android has a bug with canvas.clipRect, they have optimized it, but on some android apis it simple don't work after optimization ) I found an issue.

So fix - disable hrdware acceleration for this view

```
    (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19 && mCropShape == CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL) {
        //TURN off hardware acceleration
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```